# XSLT Checking duplicate values in whole XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a XML like this:

```
<items>
 <item>
  <attribute>1</attribute>
 </item>
 <item>
  <attribute>2</attribute>
 </item>
 <item>
  <attribute>3</attribute>
 </item>
 <item>
  <attribute>2</attribute>
 </item>
 <item>
  <attribute>1</attribute>
 </item>
 <item>
  <attribute>1</attribute>
 </item>
 <item>
  <attribute>4</attribute>
 </item>
</items>
```

And I need an XSLT to make this output:

```
<items>
 <item>
  <attribute>1</attribute>
 </item>
 <item>
  <attribute>2</attribute>
 </item>
 <item>
  <attribute></attribute>
 </item>
 <item>
  <attribute>2</attribute>
 </item>
 <item>
  <attribute>1</attribute>
 </item>
 <item>
  <attribute>1</attribute>
 </item>
 <item>
  <attribute></attribute>
 </item>
</items>
```

Basically I want the XSLT to only show  value if appears at least twice in the whole file. I only can do it with XSLT 1.0, is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the output shown in your question by using:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="att" match="attribute" use="." />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="attribute[count(key('att', .)) = 1]">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Interesting answer. I'm trying to understand the "count(key('att', .)) = 1" predicate. Instinctively I would have used >1, but you solution works. Could you please explain why the count=1 when there are more than one of this element in the key? Thanks.

Comment: @Sebastien The rule is to copy the element *as i*s. This is handled by the identity transform template. The exception is to copy only the element, but not its value. This exception is applied to elements whose value appears only once. Thus only values that appear at least twice end up being copied.